# How to debug my unconventional Java calculator?

Tags: java, debugging, calculator

I just finished programming a calculator that performs the four basic arithmetic operations, plus six trigonometric operations, in an interface so minimalistic that it just lets the user enter the expression and displays the result, with no need for separate input of operands and operator.

I think it saves time for the user and would look more finished, for lack of a better word, if it would only work.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator
{
public static String getOperator(String expression)          
{
    int counter=0;                                          

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)                                 
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(expression.charAt(i)))      
            counter++;                                        
    }                                                      

    if (counter==3)                                       
        return expression.substring(0, 3);
    else
    {
        for (int j=0; j<expression.length(); j++)
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(j))==false)
            {
              if (expression.charAt(j)!='.')
                return Character.toString(expression.charAt(j));
            }
        }
    }

    return "false";
}

public static double getFirstOperand(String operator, String expression)
{
    return Double.parseDouble(expression.substring(expression.indexOf(operator)+1));
}

public static String getOperatorType(String expression)
{
    int counter=0;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(expression.charAt(i)))
            counter++;
    }

    if (counter==3)
        return "Trigonometrical";
    else
        return "Arithemtic";
}

public static double getResult(String operator, double operand)
{
    if (operator.equals("sin"))
        return Math.sin(operand);
    if (operator.equals("cos"))
        return Math.cos(operand);
    if (operator.equals("tan"))
        return Math.tan(operand);
    if (operator.equals("cot"))
        return 1/Math.tan(operand);
    if (operator.equals("cosec"))
        return 1/Math.sin(operand);
    else
        return 1/Math.cos(operand);      
}

public static double getSecondOperand(String expression)
{
    return Double.parseDouble(expression.substring(0, expression.indexOf(expression)));
}

public static double getResult(String operator, double operand1, double operand2)
{
    if (operator.equals("*"))
        return operand1*operand2;
    if (operator.equals("+"))
        return operand1+operand2;
    if (operator.equals("/"))
        return operand2/operand1;
    else
        return operand2-operand1;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String command="", operator="", operatorType="";
    double operand1=0.0, operand2=0.0, result=0.0;

    while (command.equals("EXIT")=false)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter command: ");
        command = sc.next();

        operator = getOperator(command);
        operand1 = getFirstOperand(operator, command);
        operatorType = getOperatorType(command);

        if (operatorType.equals("Trigonometrical"))
            result=getResult(operator, operand1);
        if (operatorType.equals("Arithmetic"))
        {
            operand2 = getSecondOperand(command);
            result=getResult(operator, operand1, operand2); 
        }

        System.out.println("Result="+result);
    }
}
}
```

Somehow, whatever I input, the result is always 0.0.

```
Enter command:
45*2
Result=0.0
Enter command:
2+2
Result=0.0
```

I don't understand where the problem is. I've searched through the code tens of times, but I just don't see it.

UPDATE: Thanks for all your help, guys. The calculator finally works as it should. In fact, nearly all the problems were caused by a single lethal error in getSecondOperand. I've fixed the code now and the repaired code is given below.

Comment: You should do some debugging (rather than just looking at your code).

Comment: Also consider the difference between `==` and `equals()` ;-)

Comment: As a start, use `equals()` to compare strings, not `==`. And you should use enums instead of strings in this case.

Comment: MattR I have used equals() everywhere I have compared strings. Oh, wait. I think I see where I missed the equals() thing. I'll get back with the results of the repaired code in a minute.

Comment: Okay, so I fixed the typo, and the equals() problem. But now, I'm getting the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at Calculator.getSecondOperand(Calculator.java:69)
 at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `"Arithmetic"` in `getOperatorType()`:

```
public static String getOperatorType(String expression)
{
    int counter=0;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(expression.charAt(i)))
            counter++;
    }

    if (counter==3)
        return "Trigonometrical";
    else
        return "Arithemtic";
}
```

This is why you should avoid Strings for such cases, and favor [Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead.

Furthermore, you're comparing Strings using `==`, which won't work. Use `equals()` instead. Or, use [Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead.

Comment: There's a lot more bugs going on in your code. I suggest you use a debugger to find out.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at Calculator.getSecondOperand(Calculator.java:69)
 at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:103)

Comment: Exactly, use a debugger. We're not here to completely debug your program.

Comment: I've debugged it using NetBeans more than once. It can't find the problem.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to parse an empty String to a Double at `getSecondOperand()` at line 69.

Comment: You have compilation errors:
here: `while (command.equals("EXIT")=0)`
and here: `if (operatorType.eqauals("Trigonometrical"))`

Comment: You have wrong string constants names to operatorType.
`Arithmetic != Arithemtic`
Use enums (as others proposed) or declare your keywords as static final, e.g.:
`final static String Arithmetic = "Arithmetic";`
and use that constant everywhere in code.

Comment: Finally `expression.substring(0, expression.indexOf(expression))` always evaluates to empty string since `expression.indexOf(expression)` is 0

Comment: Thanks, krzydyn. You solved my problem. The code was actually supposed to be expression.substring(0, expression.indexOf(operator)) with the getOperand function having operator as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator
{
public static String getOperator(String expression)
{
    int counter=0;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(expression.charAt(i)))
            counter++;
    }

    if (counter==3)
        return expression.substring(0, 3);
    else
    {
        for (int j=0; j<expression.length(); j++)
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(j))==false)
                return Character.toString(expression.charAt(j));
        }
    }

    return "false";
}

public static double getFirstOperand(String operator, String expression)
{
    return Double.parseDouble(expression.substring(expression.lastIndexOf(operator)+1));
}

public static String getOperatorType(String expression)
{
    int counter=0;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(expression.charAt(i)))
            counter++;
    }

    if (counter==3)
        return "Trigonometrical";
    else
        return "Arithmetic";
}

public static double getResult(String operator, double operand)
{
    if (operator.equals("sin"))
        return Math.sin(operand);
    if (operator.equals("cos"))
        return Math.cos(operand);
    if (operator.equals("tan"))
        return Math.tan(operand);
    if (operator.equals("cot"))
        return 1/Math.tan(operand);
    if (operator.equals("cosec"))
        return 1/Math.sin(operand);
    else
        return 1/Math.cos(operand);      
}

public static double getSecondOperand(String expression, String operator)
{
    return Double.parseDouble(expression.substring(0, expression.indexOf(operator)));
}

public static double getResult(String operator, double operand1, double operand2)
{
    if (operator.equals("*"))
        return operand1*operand2;
    if (operator.equals("+"))
        return operand1+operand2;
    if (operator.equals("/"))
        return operand2/operand1;
    else
        return operand2-operand1;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String command="", operator="", operatorType="";
    double operand1=0.0, operand2=0.0, result=0.0;
    char exitNow='0';

    while (exitNow=='0'||exitNow=='N')
    {
        System.out.println("Enter command: ");
        command = sc.next();

        operator = getOperator(command);
        operand1 = getFirstOperand(operator, command);
        operatorType = getOperatorType(command);

        if (operatorType.equals("Trigonometrical"))
            result=getResult(operator, operand1);
        if (operatorType.equals("Arithmetic"))
        {
            operand2 = getSecondOperand(command, operator);
            result=getResult(operator, operand1, operand2); 
        }

        System.out.println("Result="+result+"\nExit now(1/0)(Y/N)");
        exitNow=sc.next().charAt(0);            
    }
}
}
```